# How to add a search bar at the bottom of a table view in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am developing an iOS application, and I want to add a search button that initiates a search of a table view. When searching, the search bar should not be scrolled with the table cells.

Comment: Do you have a specific question or are you looking for someone to do the entire implementation for you?

Comment: @jszumski actually i can add searchbar and implement search functionality but the problem is that it is scroll down or up with the table cells which i don't want.

Answer (score 2):

To make a search bar (or any view really) "stick" to the top or bottom of a `UITableView` there are two approaches:

- Adjust the frame of the table to be the view height minus the height of your bar, and then set the bar's frame to `{0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.tableView.frame)}`, which would position it statically at the bottom of the view.  If you are using a stock `UITableViewController`, you'll need to do some additional work because `self.view` and `self.tableView` both point to the same object.  You'll need to set a new `UIView` to `self.view` which will then be the container for the table view and your search bar view.
- Add the bar as a subview of table, then implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` in your controller and use `scrollViewDidScroll:` (which fires whenever the user scrolls the view) to update the bar's position.  The new position would be something like:

  ```
  CGRect adjustedFrame = self.searchBarView.frame;
  adjustedFrame.origin.y = self.tableView.contentOffset.y + CGRectGetHeight(self.tableView.frame) - CGRectGetHeight(self.searchBarView.frame);
  self.searchBarView.frame = adjustedFrame;
  ```